# Android deep links - allow use of subdomain URLs, with assetlinks.json on organizational domain?

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've used Android App Studio's App Links Assistant to map my URL to `MainActivity.kt`, and I can click a link in an email to open my app in the simulator.

The URL mapping when declared exactly, e.g. `https://myorg.com/open-in-app`, opens the app as desired.

If I pass my email through an email service that implements link wrapping with HTTPS, I have to use a subdomain. So, for example wrapped link can look like

`https://track.myorg.com/open-in-app/xyzzy`

In iOS / Xcode, I can set up multiple domain associations for a given app, with wildcards for subdomains as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains). iOS fetches the `apple-app-site-association` file from the subdomain's, *or* the organizational domain's `/.well-known` path. Apple recommends the org domain in the first instance [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), which is handy for supporting the same app on multiple subdomains.

Note: It's *possible* to host the `assetlinks.json` file on the subdomain, but it's a bit more complex to do this (e.g. using a CDN). `https://track.myorg.com` usually maps to the email service, which returns a redirect to the landing page. For everyone not using the app, the link will open in their browser.

In Android, is there an equivalent, i.e. host the `assetlinks.json` file in one place - on the org domain - and still deep link to URLs with subdomains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing on the Android Studio simulator, device Pixel 2, Android API level 30.

`assetlinks.json` file can be picked up from the organizational domain of a link, or from the actual (sub-domain) of a link.

The sub-domain also works via a 301 redirect, which is necessary for some CDNs such as CloudFlare. Others (such as AWS CloudFront) can host the files directly.

See also: [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-wrong-hacked-and-correct-way-of-android-deep-linking-for-redirected-multisite-with-autoverify-5c72fb1f8053)

Comment: Article is behind a paywall.